# How to be sure Progress Bar is stopped

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I know that to "stop" the ProgressBar one needs to set its visibility to `View.GONE`. But ... does that really stop it? There's an animation going in the background that animates the view. Is that animation stopping once it detects the progress bar is `GONE` or `INVISIBILE`? I really don't want to have a progress bar continuously running in the background, when not needed. It's a waste of processing power.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `ProgressBar.java` I found:

```
/**
 * Returns whether the ProgressBar is animating or not. This is essentially the same
 * as whether the ProgressBar is {@link #isIndeterminate() indeterminate} and visible,
 * as indeterminate ProgressBars are always animating, and non-indeterminate
 * ProgressBars are not animating.
 *
 * @return true if the ProgressBar is animating, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isAnimating() {
    return isIndeterminate() && getWindowVisibility() == VISIBLE && isShown();
}

void startAnimation() {
    if (getVisibility() != VISIBLE || getWindowVisibility() != VISIBLE) {
        return;
    }
    ...


@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    if (mIndeterminate) {
        stopAnimation();
    }
    ...
```

I think, `ProgressBar` will stop animating after you hide it.